# PyQt5 Display QMessageBox and QInputDialog immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I was curious what makes the QInputDialog and the QMessageBox.question always show immediately? With other PyQT elements, there is an initial sequence that is required to display the UI contents.

```py
# Example of a Basic PyQT5 UI Application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QWidget()
w.resize(250, 150)
w.move(300, 300)
w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've been trying to find the proper documentation but haven't seen anything that stands out. So I was hoping someone could point out either how I should modify the widget class or where I can find the proper documentation.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QLabel, QMessageBox, QHBoxLayout, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

class QuestionPopup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, question = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Question Popup'
        self.left = 250
        self.top = 50
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.question = question
        self._response = None
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        buttonReply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'PyQt5 message', self.question, QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if buttonReply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.response = True
        else:
            self.response = False

        self.show() 

    def getText(self):
        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Get text","Your name:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")
        if okPressed and text != '':
            print(text)
```

My goal is to create custom dialog boxes that will show images and ask for user input about the images. My code is pretty complex and I cannot simply just display a new UI window. I need the functionality that allows both QMessageBox and QInputDialog to immediately appear.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean?

Comment: Sure, I believe I may have been a bit vague. I have a main UI already running via python + QML. I have this submodule that has no real reference to the main UI other than that it is spawned by it. This other UI is written with pyqt. To prompt a user from this portion of the code, I need to have UI elements that can essentially spawn themselves. The QInputDialog and QMessageBox seem to do this.

Comment: mmmm, your explanation is not clear, explain yourself better. But on the other hand the logic in QML and QtWidgets are different, so using the solution for QtWidgets (which it seems you want) does not necessarily work in QML. What do you mean *show immediately*?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm still relatively new to Qt and this project has grown quite a bit in scope. If you look at my original post, the if I create an instance of my QuestionPopup() class while my main UI is running, it will be called exactly when I expect it to be. If I create a class that contains the code from this example, https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-textbox-example/, the window does not appear. So I was curious what sets the QMessagebox and the other QElements apart from one another. Again, sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: @Knoose all of your explanations are clear, eyllanesc just can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

The methods referenced in your question are static members of QInputDialog and QMessageBox which are synchronous, blocking calls. This is emulated by instead of calling show, calling exec on the dialog. exec is similar to show (in pyqt, exec is exec_ to avoid clashing with the python builtin exec), but it actually blocks all of your other UI components until it gives control (it technically does this by pausing the main event loop and running it's own specific to the dialog which eventually gives up control). See more about this here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#exec

Note that this is a behavior specific to these static functions mentioned. You can create your own QMessageBox without using these functions and it will behave in what is considered the normal way, i.e. not showing up until you explicitly call show.

Here is a sample function that shows a high level detail of how QMessageBox.static may be implemented under the hood (though this is not the actual code):

```py
    def question(parent, title, message, buttons):
        message_box = QMessageBox(question_icon, title, message, buttons)
        return message_box.exec_()
```

The gist is to get the behavior that those static functions are using, you need to call exec_ on a dialog and not show. Note that exec_ is only available on specific widget types, most notably anything inheriting from QDialog. You also should take note of the fact that exec is a synchronous, blocking call, which means that nothing else that operates on the main thread of your application will run until that dialog is dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

As @TheKewlStore says, the methods you reference are static and are limited as to what you can modify. They contain built in properties that cause them to show immediately rather than requiring the use of `show()` or `app.exec_()` Below addresses this part of your question: '...how to modify the widget class' to display your image and allow user input as well as display a message box.

This will start by creating a simple message box, then upon its closure, will create and display a basic dialog box that can show an image, a line of text to instruct the user, a place for the user to enter text, as well as an Ok and Cancel button - I only hooked up the OK button to simply print the user's input. Obviously you can plug in whatever commands you want for the button and what happens with the user input. I also used some grid layouts, mostly because I like the way it keeps stuff clean, but they're not mandatory to make this work. One could also make the dimensions of the boxes much more dynamic, I just didn't feel the need for it here.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import PyQt5
import os

class MsgBox(object):
    def setupUi(self, show_msgbox):
        show_msgbox.setObjectName("show_msgbox")
        show_msgbox.setText('Show your message text here')

class MsgPrompt(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMessageBox, MsgBox):
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MsgPrompt, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        super(MsgPrompt, self).exec_()

class UserInput(object):
    def setupUi(self, get_user_input):
    # Basic shape
    self.width = 425
    get_user_input.setObjectName("get_user_input")
    get_user_input.resize(425, self.width)
    self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(get_user_input)
    self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(11, 10, 401, 381))
    self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
    self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
    # Creating the grid layout for most of the display elements
    self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 381, 361))
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
    self.get_user_input_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.get_user_input_layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
    self.get_user_input_layout.setObjectName("get_user_input_layout")
    # Grid layout for the buttons
    self.buttonLayoutGrid = QtWidgets.QWidget(get_user_input)
    self.buttonLayoutGrid.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 390, 401, 41))
    self.buttonLayoutGrid.setObjectName("buttonLayoutGrid")
    self.buttonLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.buttonLayoutGrid)
    self.buttonLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.buttonLayout.setObjectName("buttonLayout")
    # Adding buttons    
    self.buttonOK = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.buttonLayoutGrid)
    self.buttonOK.setObjectName("buttonOK")
    self.buttonOK.setText("OK")
    self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.buttonOK, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.buttonCancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.buttonLayoutGrid)
    self.buttonCancel.setObjectName("buttonCancel")
    self.buttonCancel.setText("CANCEL")
    self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.buttonCancel, 0, 2, 1, 1)
    # Adding the place for the image
    self.image = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.get_user_input_layout.addWidget(self.image, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    # Add instructions for the user
    self.user_prompt_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.user_prompt_text.setText('WHAT IS THIS PIC?')
    self.user_prompt_text.setAlignment(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
    self.get_user_input_layout.addWidget(self.user_prompt_text, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    # Add a field for the user to enter text    
    self.user_input_box = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.user_input_box.setObjectName('user_input_box')
    self.user_input_box.setEnabled(True)
    self.get_user_input_layout.addWidget(self.user_input_box, 2, 0, 1, 1)
    # This is an optional call
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(get_user_input)

class UserInputPrompt(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QDialog, UserInput):
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    def __init__(self, path_to_image):
        super(UserInputPrompt, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.path_to_image = path_to_image
        self.user_input_box.setFocus()
        self.buttonOK.clicked.connect(self.get_user_input)
        self.image.setPixmap(PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap(self.path_to_image).scaledToWidth(self.width
        self.image.show()
        super(UserInputPrompt, self).exec_()        

    def get_user_input(self):
        print(self.user_input_box.text())

MsgPrompt()
UserInputPrompt('your_image_file.jpg')
```